# Extend JSF component CommandLink

Tags: jsf

How can I extend a jsf primeface link? I want to use the `actionListener` attribute with the link and overwrite the `encodeAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a composite component as a wrapper and use a backing class:

```
<composite:interface componentType="my.special.Class">
...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

  // place your wrapped component here

</composite:implementation>
```

Overwrite the encodeChildren method in the backing Class.

Please note: This is rather a hack than a clean solution. Depending on what you want to do a custom renderer would be appropriate.